how can I use SVG in nunjucks templates
I would like to create a nunjucks template to load SVG dynamically from a directory, by passing the icon name the template should render the  contents of SVG using javascript
tried with {{% include <filename>.SVG %}}

Please add a minimal reproducible example and clarify if this error also applies to raster images (e.g jpegs, png etc). If your SVG is a icon sprite it may not render anything unless you create a <use> reference.

I could be wrong, but perhaps you mean you want to Learn how to implement an HTML5 canvas app into your nunjucks environment? Is that what you really want?

You don't provide any info where (server side or in a browser) you are using nunjucks, so I suppose it's a browser.
Your goal is to place a some file content to a page by a provided url. It can be solved by a custom function: {{ addIcon ('yourfile.svg') }}. But there is a problem: by default nunjucks is used in synchronous mode and load file (fetch) is an asynchronous operation. There is 3 ways to solve it.

Use nunjucks in async mode. Example is here.
Preload all svg before call nunjucks-render and pass an array of icons to the render.
Place a some specific static block to a page and modify it by a mutation observer.

var nunjucks  = require('nunjucks');
var env = nunjucks.configure();
env.addFilter('addIcon', function(file) {
    return  `<div class = "runtime-icon" filename = '${file}'></div>`;
});
// With it you can call {{ addIcon('my.svg') }} in a template 
// to add on a page `<div class = "runtime-icon" filename = 'my.svg'></div>`

...
function loadIcon (mutations) {
    // scan page for a new element with runtime-icon-class
    // get its filename-attribute
    // fetch file
    // replace div-element by the file content
}

const observer = new MutationObserver(loadIcon)
observer.observe(document, {childList: true, subtree: true})

